# My Android phone shows insufficient memory even after deleting all the apps on internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

Please help me on this. My android phone started behaving weird these days. I have 32GB internal memory on the phone. earlier i had only 17% used. but one fine day it started showing 99% used even after deleting all the apps on the device. I cleared the cache, user data. it would come down to 97-98%, and that space is also consumed in no time. Cleared unwanted data, moved apps and media to SD card etc, still same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Madhuk

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! May I suggest, while waiting for recommendations, that you start checking with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? It a.o. links some useful questions (with answers). Also check other questions using that tag; we've got multiple on the topic how to find out what's occupying the space. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

32GB internal memory! I envy you!

Anyways, it might be because of the android is,  which is perhaps taking up too much space.

Moreover, built in apps like Google apps and chrome cannot be moved.

Lastly, if problem persists, take your phone to an authorized service centre and explain the issue. Be sure to take a backup before going there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to analyze what eats your storage at first, and then try to eliminate the root of the problem. The root cause can be anything: a greedy (standard) app, a virus or forgotten files, copied by you, or whatever.
For analysis you can try:

1. [Standard Storage applet](http://img.techentice.com/img/cached-data1.jpg). By tapping on **Cache** you can easily clean app's cache, which can free up to several gigabytes.
2. Special apps [like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive&hl=en)